# Повторение предлога

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, однородные-члены

*В нашем блоге мы будем давать практические советы по общению с людьми, [по] личному влиянию и [по] лидерству.*

С одной стороны, повторение предлога необходимо, так как логически один совет не может быть одновременно по общению с людьми, по личному влиянию и по лидерству. С другой стороны, здесь нет необходимости подчеркивать множественность советов и разграничение их по характеру — практические советы воспринимаются как нечто целостное, включающее в себя некоторое количество советов по каждой теме. Также без повторения предлога предложение более благозвучно.

Comment: "На блоге"? Скорее, "в блоге".

Comment: На мой взгляд, "советы по" звучит нормально только в том случае, когда имеется в виду "советы о том, как" (советы по общению с людьми =  советы о том, как общаться с людьми), в остальных случаях я бы заменил на "советы о личном влиянии и о лидерстве".

Comment: 1. Исправил. 2. Введите в поисковике "советы по" — "Советы по поиску работы", "Советы по правильному питанию", "Советы по безопасности", "Советы по макияжу". А теперь введите "советы о"...

Comment: Есть *советы по развитию лидерских качеств*, *советы, которые помогут стать лидером*, *уроки лидерства*, но от *советов по лидерству* увольте. Если человек так выражается, какой из него советчик?

Comment: На мой взгляд звучит приемлемо. Повторять предлоги не нужно.   Слово "лидерство" в данном случае употреблено не в каком-нибудь привычном словарном значении, а в новом, взятом из английского "leadership", коннотации которого весьма разнообразны. Не уверен, допустимо ли такое использование в строгом книжном стиле, но в блоге подобного направления его не избежать.

Comment: @grizzly Ваше мнение, что предлог «по» повторять не нужно, основано на той же посылке, что и моё?

Comment: Мнение основано на чувстве языка, не более. Если бы я мог предложить аргументы, я бы дал ответ. Предложение звучит нормально, пусть и не идеально, но улучшить его я не могу (да и другие участники тоже, похоже).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, действительно, с одной стороны:

- "по, по, по" — звучит надоедливо.
  Добавьте ещё пару "по", и посетители с тонким языковым вкусом вряд ли задержатся на страницах блога.
- без повтора предлогов смысл не теряется, суть остаётся ясна

Вообще, на мой взгляд, повтор любого слова 3 раза в небольшом предложении неуместен, если это не художественный прием.

С другой стороны, действительно, видим конфликт смысловых связей.

Если во что бы то ни стало нужно сохранить конструкцию, можно найти компромисс и убрать одно "по", а именно последнее:

*В нашем блоге мы будем давать практические советы по общению с людьми, по лидерству и личному влиянию.*

Как говорится, и волки, и овцы.

Другой вопрос — нравится ли вам само предложение, на вид и на слух, звучит ли оно для вас убедительно и богато?

На слух лично мне не нравятся слова "люди", "практический", "лидерство".
Слово "лидерство" я бы заменил на "лидер" или "лидерский".
И вообще избегал бы подобных слов — с четырьмя согласными подряд.

Кроме того в "общении с людьми" "люди" не нужны (в данном случае — плеоназм, в контексте и так подразумевается общение с людьми, а не с домашними питомцами, например.)

Если убрать "людей", то "давать практические советы по общению" — звучит бедно и серо.

"практические советы" я бы заменил, например, на "универсальные" (на мой вкус, поярче и приятнее на слух)

Ещё, просто по ощущениям сравните следующие два варианта:

*В нашем блоге мы будем давать*

и

*В нашем блоге вы найдёте*

Всего пара слов меняет фрейм, включает вовлечённость читателя.

Наконец, можно обогатить и структурировать предложение (а заодно кардинально решить проблему "по") например, таким образом:

*В нашем блоге вы найдёте универсальные советы по:*

- *ведению эффективной коммуникации*
- *усилению личного влияния*
- *развитию лидерских качеств*

Comment: @ me2 beats,если автору хочется оставить свой вариант, то предлоги нужны. Но его текст стилистически неудачен,  поэтому ваш вариант достаточно хорош.

Answer (score 1):

Вот что говорится в справочнике по литературному редактированию Д. Э. Розенталя и К. И Былинского.

Не следует пропускать предлог при отдаленной смысловой связи между однородными членами, например: **Он много путешествовал по Украине, по степям Средней Азии, по сибирской тайге (перечисленные слова не входят как видовые понятия в одно общее родовое понятие).**

Думаю,  ваш пример подпадает под этот пункт. Так как и в нем присутствует отдаленная смысловая связь.